# How do I use a generic List with my Arc Objects code?

Tags: arcobjects, feature-class, list

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a list of all geoms in a Feature Class
/// </summary>
/// <param name="FClass">The Feature Class</param>
/// <returns>a List of Geometries</returns>
private List<T> GetGeometries<T>(IFeatureClass FClass)
{
    List<T> List_Geometries = new List<T>();

    IQueryFilter aQF = new QueryFilter();
    aQF.WhereClause = "";
    ISelectionSet selectionSet = FClass.Select(aQF, esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeIDSet, esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionNormal, null);
    IEnumIDs enumId = selectionSet.IDs;
    int nFeatures = selectionSet.Count;
    enumId.Reset();
    int id;
    for (int j = 0; j < nFeatures; j++)
    {
        id = enumId.Next();
        IGeometry pGeom = FClass.GetFeature(id).Shape;
        List_Geometries.Add((T)pGeom);
    }
    return List_Geometries;
}
```

I don't get any diagnostics errors on the above routine. However I do get an error when I attempt to call this method. How can I call this method from the following set of code?

```
private List<IPoint> GetPointsList(IFeatureRepository Bfr)
{
IFeatureClass Bfc = Bfr.GetFeatureClassByName("PointFeatureClass");
List<IPoint> listPoints = GetGeometries(Bfc);
return listPoints;
}
```

By the way, this is not the way to do it, but I'm just trying to give an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `List<IPoint> listPoints = GetGeometries<IPoint>(Bfc);`  (Been a while since I have done C#)

Comment: @NathanW  Yes, it was such a simple thing.  Thanks!  I think we were both posting the answer at the same time :-)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it on my own.  The following method of calling this routine works:

```
   private List<IPoint> GetPointsList(IFeatureRepository Bfr)
    {
        IFeatureClass Bfc = Bfr.GetFeatureClassByName("PointFeatureClass");
        List<IPoint> listPoints = GetGeometries<IPoint>(Bfc);
        return listPoints;
    }
```